# Making a class perform tasks when it exits scope of `with` statement

Tags: python, class, with-statement

Is there a class attribute that I can override to make an instance of a class perform something before it exits the scope of a `with` statement?

For example, we can ensure that we close a file handle when we're done with it:

```
with open(PATH, 'wb') as f:
    f.write("SOME TEXT")
```

If I wrote a class that needs a writer to persist for the lifetime of the class like this:

```
class MyWriter(object):

   def __init__(self, path):
       self.f = open(path, 'wb')
       self.buffer = ''

   def write(self, text):
       self.buffer += text
       # Just a toy example, naively relying on file system
       # page cache should outperform this 
       if len(self.buffer) >= 4096:
           self.flush()

   def flush(self):
       f.write(self.buffer)
       self.buffer = ''

   def close(self):
       self.flush()
       self.f.close()
```

then I would like to force a call of `.close()` and flush before I exit the scope of `with`:

```
with MyWriter(PATH) as mw:
    mw.write("SOME TEXT")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is **context manager**. That's what your object is called when it's used with the `with` statement.

There is very good [documentation on context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) in the official Python documentation. There is also some great background information and some good examples in [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).